# Ubuntu 18.04 fresh install fails - won't boot

Tags: boot, drivers, 18.04

I have just attempted to install 18.04 on my current 16.04 system.

Gear is a Gigabyte AM3+ mobo and AMX FX4100 chip (bulldozer).

I created a USB boot device, started it and the system hangs with a blank screen after the keyboard selection prompt.

If I move into the boot options and select expert mode, I get:

`ACPI Exception: Could not find/resolve named package element: LNKD (20170831/dspkginit-381).`

If I turn off all the boot options (noacpi, nolacpi, etc.), I get a screen flashing boot information (but it pops up for 1/4 of a second, then disappears).  I managed to snap a photo of it - last error is 

`[ 62.772706 ] Buffer I/O error on dev sde, logical block 1944560, async page read`

I have previously had much difficulty getting, initially 14.04 to work on this  system, and the upgrade to 16.04 was almost impossible and is unstable.  In 14.04 I used the alternate boot disc, which worked fine.

During the 16.04 upgrade process I tried many different graphics cards with varying errors but ultimately, failure, returning to my current:  AMD CEDAR (DRM 2.36.0 / 3.13.0-143-generic, LLVM 5.0.0).  I apologize that I cannot say what actually made it work - I think that the process of swapping cards and fiddling back and forth between proprietary drivers may have something to do with it.

Also of note is that in 16.04 I cannot boot to kernel versions 4.x - I must always fall back to the 3.13.0-143 kernel.

Below is my dmesg output.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.13.0-143-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-010) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) ) #192-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 27 10:45:36 UTC 2018 (Ubuntu 3.13.0-143.192-generic 3.13.11-ckt39)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-143-generic root=UUID=abc0d25d-ac6b-43f9-8634-411a4ba1d5a0 ro acpi=off noapic nolapic quiet splash nomdmonddf nomdmonisw nomdmonddf nomdmonisw nomdmonddf nomdmonisw nomdmonddf nomdmonisw
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009f7ff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009f800-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000f0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000cfdeffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cfdf0000-0x00000000cfdf0fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cfdf1000-0x00000000cfdfffff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cfe00000-0x00000000cfefffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000e0000000-0x00000000efffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000022effffff] usable
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[    0.000000] SMBIOS 2.4 present.
[    0.000000] DMI: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. GA-870A-USB3/GA-870A-USB3, BIOS F5d 10/21/2011
[    0.000000] Kernel/User page tables isolation: disabled
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
[    0.000000] e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
[    0.000000] No AGP bridge found
[    0.000000] e820: last_pfn = 0x22f000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000000] MTRR default type: uncachable
[    0.000000] MTRR fixed ranges enabled:
[    0.000000]   00000-9FFFF write-back
[    0.000000]   A0000-BFFFF uncachable
[    0.000000]   C0000-C7FFF write-protect
[    0.000000]   C8000-FFFFF uncachable
[    0.000000] MTRR variable ranges enabled:
[    0.000000]   0 base 000000000000 mask FFFF80000000 write-back
[    0.000000]   1 base 000080000000 mask FFFFC0000000 write-back
[    0.000000]   2 base 0000C0000000 mask FFFFF0000000 write-back
[    0.000000]   3 base 0000CFE00000 mask FFFFFFE00000 uncachable
[    0.000000]   4 disabled
[    0.000000]   5 disabled
[    0.000000]   6 disabled
[    0.000000]   7 disabled
[    0.000000] TOM2: 000000022f000000 aka 8944M
[    0.000000] x86 PAT enabled: cpu 0, old 0x7040600070406, new 0x7010600070106

Sorry I don't have anywhere to post a copy of the dmesg output fully and I can't seem to embed a copy of it inline due to size and apparent spamminess according to the filters.

Comment: Did you create a new partition to test 18.04 on? It will come with a 4.x kernel as default so you might want to fix those problems on your existing 16.04 system too.

Comment: It's hanging before any partition control can be exerted.  I suspect a video card problem, but it's difficult to pin down.  X11 seems more complicated than it used to be.  And I'm happy to trash the 16.04 install - /home is a different partition so no data loss.